# Is there an equivalent to triu_indices (numpy) in Eigen?

Tags: python, c++, numpy, eigen

I want to extract the upper triangular part of matrix (3x3) as a vector.

In python with numpy I can do something like :

```
myMat = myMat[np.triu_indices(3)]
```

Is there an equivalent with Eigen in cpp ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out the Eigen equivalent :

```
myMat.topRightCorner(3,3)
```

Comment: `topRightCorner` returns the top right block, not the upper triangular matrix.

Comment: Yes I realized that just after. Do you have a solution maybe ?